# How do I perform a proper if function in this case?

Tags: python, if-statement, input

This code keeps me asking the first if input(x) question after giving the program a defined string (e.g. "add").
After typing it in a few times it gives me the desired output.

Why not in first try?
Further, how do I perform a loop such as the program ends when the input is "end"?

Thank you in advance.
Best.

```
    x = """Wählen Sie eine der folgenden vorgegebenen Operationen: (add/subtract/multiply/divide/end/history)
"""
a = "Erste Zahl: "
b = "Zweite Zahl: "
ops = ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide", "history", "end"]
list = []

if input(x) in ops:

    list.append(input(x))

    if input(x) == "add":
        print(int(input(a)) + int(input(b)))

    elif input(x) == "subtract":
        print(int(input(a)) - int(input(b)))

    elif input(x) == "multiply":
        print(int(input(a)) * int(input(b)))

    elif input(x) == "divide":
        print(int(input(a)) / int(input(b)))

    elif input(x) == "history":
        print(list)

    elif input(x) == "end":
        print("Das Programm wird beendet")

else:
    print("""Geben Sie bitte eine gültige Eingabe ein""")
```

Comment: You're calling `input()` repeatedly. Naming a variable `list` is a terrible idea, be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `input()`, you're asking for *new* input.  You probably want to call `input()` just *once*, save the result in a variable, and then compare against that variable:

```
answer = input("Please type your answer ")

if answer == "hello":
    print("You typed a greeting")
elif answer == "hamburger":
    print("You are eating lunch")
... etc
```